# QSelectSection in quickDialog using JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, quickdialog

I am trying to build the `QSelectSection in JSON.` I am using this:

```
{
   "type":"QSelectSection",         
    "title":"multiselect",            
    "items":[[1, 2, 3]],           
    "multipleAllowed":true            
}
```

But when I build and run, I get this error:

```
'-[QSelectSection setParentSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9fb2020
```

Is it possible to build a multiselect with the QuickDialog framework? Or what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is:

```
{
  "type":"QSelectSection",         
  "title":"multiselect",            
  "items":[1, 2, 3],           
  "multipleAllowed":true            
}
```